# is this sound [j]?

Tags: ipa, pronunciation

is the sound in this [recording](https://voca.ro/12iChAUa9myi) [j]? or is it just [i]? I feel like all my post-vocalic /i/'s are Pronounced like [j] but I'm not sure.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because judgements on individual pronunciations aren't helpful for other users of the site.

Comment: Haven't we seen a very similar question just yesterday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a general answer to all "is this IPA [X]", supply your favorite symbol. Use the [expert performances](https://www.internationalphoneticassociation.org/IPAcharts/inter_chart_2018/IPA_2018.html) as your standard for comparison. Evaluate your performance compared to that of the experts, and also compare your performance to the expert's pronunciation of other most-similar sounds. In this case, that would be [ʎ]. Luckily, you picked a difficult example: it is not clear which is it closer to.

One problem is that there is a range of variation in the expert performances, and there is auditory overlap in the case of [ʎ] and [j]. Another problem is that the judgments should be made by a trained expert (you can remedy this issue by taking the UCL training courses). However, your question was about comparison of [j] and [i], which is an invalid comparison. Note that consonants are performed in the contexts *Cɑ, ɑˈCɑ*, but vowels are produced alone as *V*, abnormally sustained. Comparisons of segments have to be in comparable contexts. There are good reasons why you don't get expert performances of isolated [j]. So in principle, it is impossible to decide on purely phonetic grounds whether you are performing [ɑˈjɑ] or [ɑĭˈɑ]. That issue has to be decided by appeal to phonological arguments, and therefore has to be [ɑˈjɑ] *as performed in a specific language*.